# SHA256 signature generation not matching: Java vs Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sha256

I am converting a Java code to Objective C to match signature in request with SHA256.

Here are my inputs and outputs:

#

**Java**:

```
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(client_secret.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");

Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256"); 

mac.init(key); 

byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String signature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));

log.info("signature="+signature);
```

Output is: signature=q4T4uuz482U+guKa8oRn8Enq9xJjSRYvQlYxF6TSAFQ=

**Obj C**:

```
-- (NSString*) HMACWithSec:(NSString*) secret data:(NSString*) data {

    const char *cKey = [secret cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    //Making it NSUTF8StringEncoding does not help

    const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

    NSData *hash = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: cHMAC length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    // I tried making a Hex string out of the bytes and then covering it back to ASCII or UTF-8, did not work.

    NSString* signature = [hash base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    //All base 64 methods returns same. I found this as most convenient.

    NSLog(@"%@", signature);

    return signature;
}
```

Output is: HcqgsyTj0DRYlGT1QV9L48LcvX9Zc+eX8ShXjJQEDKc=

#

I tried the following too:

```
NSString *s8 = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(const char *)cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
```

Output is arbitrary chars.

**Explanation**:

Both inputs are same for secret and data. I verified with cKey and cData. After I am getting the bytes in obj c into "cHMAC". Making it a NSData and then getting the base64 string is not generating the same string.

**Question**:

What did I miss out? Any insight helps.

Comment: As I mentioned in comments using NSUTF8StringEncoding does not help. From method I am returning "signature".

Comment: It will compile, added return statement too.

Comment: Thanks all, I could solve the problem. Issue was my mistake I sent a wrong input to the key.